# How to survive Omega Flowey

Tags: undertale

Ummm... this is my first play through of Undertale. I just defeated Asgore, and now have to face the horror that is Photoshop Flowey. I have looked up his attacks on the UT wiki, I have studied almost every Steam community forum on the topic... And I still keep dying.

I'm not sure how to avoid his attacks. They seem to just about fill up the screen. I've looked at almost all the websites that I thought might help, and all I found was people boasting that they got it in the second to third try, or that I just needed to "git gud". The only answers I found were vague and inconclusive, such as "Just dodge and wait it out," completely ignoring the fact I have no clue how to dodge because his attacks pretty much fill up the screen, and they're so fast... Can any Undertale veterans please give me some pointers?

Btw, I'm trying to spare him, in case that affects how to defeat him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the majority of the Flowey fight relies on reflexes and pattern recognition. I could detail how to attempt to dodge the different combination of phases, but if you're spending time trying to consciously index the list of moves while you're playing you'll probably end up doing worse.

That said, there are a few tips in general for how to handle the fight:

1.) Until you survive all of the other hearts' attacks, the boss operates on a timer. Attempting to attack before then does effectively nothing, so don't bother trying to juke towards the button until you have the hearts' support. Once the music changes up, then you need to hammer the attack button to end the fight. Also, you can't spare Omega Flowey, so don't worry about that.

2.) You get good healing chances after each heart's attack phase when the projectiles turn green. Memorize the patterns to these sections and you can get up to 70% of your health.

3.) Despite what you say, the attacks don't all "fill up the screen." A lot of them have dumb targeting or patterns where you can shift left/right or up/down to avoid them almost flawlessly. If the vines attack out of Flowey's body or guns start shooting fire, for example, just move to the left or right. If he fires cross patterns from his eyes, you can move left and right to stay between the beams. Look for little tricks like that.

4.) Consequently, very few of the attacks leave a definitive safe space where you can hold still and avoid damage, so it's best to always be moving.