# How do you spare Photoshop Flowey?

Tags: undertale

I have tried just about everything:

- I have tried the Asgore approach and waited till he had very little health.
- Tried talking but nothing happened.

I am at a loss for what to do so I ask you for help. Please, help me by sharing your knowledge of Photoshop Flowey and how to spare him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. You must deplete his health *entirely*, after gaining the support of the other six SOULs as [described here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/328367/91981). Then, he will turn back into regular Flowey after a brief cutscene, and

> you will be offered an opportunity to spare him. You have to spare repeatedly, because like Toriel, he does not immediately accept your mercy. If you keep sparing, he will eventually "run away."